# php image delete unlink() issue on localhost

Tags: php

**image delete unlink() issue on localhost:**

My Code Snippet (Not Working):

```
if(file_exists('./uploads/Property/'.$imgnm))
{ 
    unlink('./uploads/Property/'.$imgnm);
}
```

My Code Snippet (Working):

```
if(file_exists('./uploads/Property/300X300/'.$imgthumbnm))
{
   unlink('./uploads/Property/300X300/'.$imgthumbnm);
}
```

I checked $imgnm & $imgthumbnm variable values carefully.. values are correct

then why not image getting deleted in first code snippet, please suggest me changes or idea to resolve this issue

Comment: With the `@`-sign you are surpressing error messages. Removing it will probably give you the right error message to find the problem.

Comment: @Christoph Kluge I removed @ also, but though same issue.. if condition file_exists() satisfies but unlink() not delete image

Comment: Let me quickly recap: `file_exists($file)` is true and `unlink($file)` does not delete it and also does not display any error when removing the `@`? Did you checked your logs? Otherwise I would guess your `error_reporting` is too low. Additionally `ini_set('display_errors', true)` might help also help to see the error.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', true); added though not showing any error.. but also not working

Comment: Can you perform a `realpath('./uploads/Property/300X300/'.$imgthumbnm))` and check if it results into an absolute path as string or if it returns an `false`?

Comment: for 1st code snippet, realpath() output is "C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\uploads\Property"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208749/discussion-between-christoph-kluge-and-anjali-patil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all is okay then surely issue is with variable $imgnm.. check it carefully

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `@` operator. This tells the php interpreter to ignore all errors from the given statement. To see, what is going on, and why your code is not working, remove the `@` before `unlink`.

This will assure, that you will see any error that will be produced by the call, so it should tell you right away, what is wrong and you can try to fix the problem.

Usually, using the `@` is considered a bad practice in modern php, instead I would  recommend you to use a custom [error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to make errors produce exceptions. Then you can wrap your code in a `try catch` construct and it will be much easier for you to actually handle, if something goes wrong.

Comment: @ removed though getting same issue @Jirka Vrba